# How to prevent GMSMapView refresh the text on the map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS with version 2.1.0 from Cocoapods.
Every time my app entering foreground will cause those text including road name and legends fade in from transparent. Since the placeholder in iOS app switcher has those text and legends on it, it feels like a flicker or blink. I tried official Google Map app on iOS and find out they have the same behaviour. So I wonder if there's any way to prevent this from happening.

I'm setting up the GMSMapView using the Interface Builder. It's a view with custom class GMSMapView and have a IBOutlet connected to it.